# Updating customer records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update the prepaid tips of all the customers for Bub Slug by 0.10. I tried using this but when I run it it says zero rows effected. I am not sure why?

```
update customer
  set PrePaidTip = PrePaidTip + 0.10
where firstname  in (select firstname from carrier where Firstname ='bub')
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused.  Why do you need the subquery?

```
update customer
    set PrePaidTip = PrePaidTip + 0.10
    where firstname = 'bub';
```